# Select Menu Style Not Showing

Tags: css, html-select, optionmenu

I have two select menus, and neither fully recognize the css styles I have applied. What I am doing wrong? The menus should be displaying different background color and font color when and option is selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonniebauer/6rLyW/

```
<select id="select1" onchange='OwnerType(this.value)'>
                <option value="--Choose Type--">--Choose Type--</option>
                <option value="Sole_Proprietor">Sole Proprietor</option>
                <option value="Partnership">Partnership</option>
                <option value="LLC">LLC</option>
                <option value="Private_Corporation">Private Corporation</option>
                <option value="Non_Profit_Tax_Exempt">Non-Profit/Tax Exempt</option>
                <option value="Cooperative">Cooperative</option>
                <option value="Limited_Partnership">Limited Partnership</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>

<select id="select2" onchange='ReturnPolicy(this.value)'>
                <option value="--Choose Return Policy--">--Choose Return Policy--</option>
                <option value="No_Returns">No Returns</option>
                <option value="Exchange">Exchange</option>
                <option value="30_Day_Refund">Refund within 30 Days</option>
                <option value="Other2">Other</option>
            </select>

select {
            padding: 1rem;
            margin: 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            border-bottom: 3px #898989;
            /*-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);*/
            background: #F2F2F2;
            color: #BDC3C7;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            display: inline-block;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            cursor:pointer;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 1.125em;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

select:hover {
            color: #898989;
            background: #E8E8E8;
            -webkit-transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
            -webkit-transition-property: border, color, background-color;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
            -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, linear, linear;
            -webkit-transition-delay: initial, initial, initial;
            transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
            transition-property: border, color, background-color;
            transition-duration: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
            transition-timing-function: linear, linear, linear;
            transition-delay: initial, initial, initial;
        }

select:active {
            color: #898989;
            background: #E8E8E8;
        }

        #select1.Sole_Proprietor, option[value="Sole_Proprietor"],
        #select1.Partnership, option[value="Partnership"],
        #select1.LLC, option[value="LLC"],
        #select1.Private_Corporation, option[value="Private_Corporation"],
        #select1.Non_Profit_Tax_Exempt, option[value="Non_Profit_Tax_Exempt"],
        #select1.Cooperative, option[value="Cooperative"],
        #select1.Limited_Partnership, option[value="Limited_Partnership"],
        #select1.Other, option[value="Other"] {
            background: #3498DB;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }

#select1.Sole_Proprietor:hover, option[value="Sole_Proprietor"]:hover,
        #select1.Partnership:hover, option[value="Partnership"]:hover,
        #select1.LLC:hover, option[value="LLC"]:hover,
        #select1.Private_Corporation:hover, option[value="Private_Corporation"]:hover,
        #select1.Non_Profit_Tax_Exempt:hover, option[value="Non_Profit_Tax_Exempt"]:hover,
        #select1.Cooperative:hover, option[value="Cooperative"]:hover,
        #select1.Limited_Partnership:hover, option[value="Limited_Partnership"]:hover,
        #select1.Other:hover, option[value="Other"]:hover {
            background-color: #258CD1;
            -webkit-transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
            -webkit-transition-property: border, color, background-color;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
            -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, linear, linear;
            -webkit-transition-delay: initial, initial, initial;
            transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
            transition-property: border, color, background-color;
            transition-duration: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
            transition-timing-function: linear, linear, linear;
            transition-delay: initial, initial, initial;
        }

#select2.No_Returns option[value="No_Returns"],
        #select2.Exchange option[value="Exchange"],
        #select2.30_Day_Refund option[value="30_Day_Refund"],
        #select2.Other2 option[value="Other2"] {
            background: #3498DB;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in CSS.  From the [Sitepoint reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/select):

> The select renders slightly differently depending on the browser and operating system in use, and is well known as a troublesome HTML element to style with CSS (because the display is inherited from the operating system, rather than provided by the browser).

Some style elements are still available, such as the font-family, etc., but many of them will be ignored in favor of what the user's OS dictates.